# LIMIT does not work with UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, limit

What is wrong with below code?

```
SELECT  first_name, last_name
FROM    employees
UNION ALL
SELECT  first_name, last_name
FROM    dependents
ORDER BY  last_name
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 1;
```

Even a simple query with LIMIT doesn't seem to be working :

```
SELECT  first_name, last_name
FROM    dependents
ORDER BY  last_name
LIMIT 6 OFFSET 1;
```

> Getting this error repeatedly: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe oracle does not support `LIMIT`. Try this

```
ORDER BY last_name
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY;
```

Note this syntax supports from Oracle 12c

Comment: Thanks, I tried below and it works perfectly fine:

SELECT  first_name, last_name
FROM    dependents
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY;

Comment: @Enthusiast - You are missing `Order by`, it is important to make the result consistent

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the code is that Oracle does not support `limit`.  Period.  The most recent versions support the ANSI standard `fetch first <n> rows only`.

Perhaps you intend:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY last_name) as seqnum
      FROM (SELECT first_name, last_name FROM employees
            UNION ALL
            SELECT first_name, last_name
            FROM dependents
           ) e
      ORDER BY last_name
     ) e
WHERE seqnum BETWEEN 1 and 7;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordan, I'm a newbie and simply practicing the code on apex.oracle.com. Got my answer :)